# plot with hist function get wrong normalized probability density figure

Tags: python-3.x, histogram

## I want drow a simple hist plot, with density=True， the data saved in the data.txt file, I put here:

> -3.159589616094560238e-02
>   -2.238517986981702901e-02
>   3.685513259832978727e-02
>   5.551115123125782702e-17
>   3.855829197377269590e-02
>   1.106747485805819609e-01
>   -1.343976685751569478e-01
>   4.594910529316376113e-03
>   4.908490856818659154e-04
>   3.419692699076753994e-02
>   -1.000969353410680052e-02
>   -3.022899285774027778e-02
>   -5.537409517542163373e-02
>   -4.602923607484266100e-02
>   3.284859133476397686e-02
>   -1.023686626680164746e-02
>   -3.664415656649880337e-02
>   8.171815787883440763e-02
>   2.999203027116759124e-02
>   5.004522795043858663e-02
>   7.388383006436807787e-02
>   6.113278573286806683e-02
>   6.386857025829173473e-02
>   3.591723008598152189e-02
>   6.549840356253561202e-02
>   1.253856364955455160e-02
>   6.041119437265624059e-02
>   6.908608718235104140e-02
>   1.134341604638248180e-01
>   -1.576914025344122727e-02
>   -2.417229901971842954e-02
>   -3.899153022868465102e-02
>   4.689096941761000670e-02
>   5.841198683607556896e-02
>   8.641413395100966399e-02
>   5.642541143884205468e-02
>   4.930903227540417433e-03
>   1.942745077277890919e-02
>   2.158310326121676281e-02
>   1.049712334090066590e-02
>   1.754053058915017171e-02
>   -2.353744351610204122e-02
>   -8.208313574505410326e-03
>   5.744397964275682611e-02
>   -1.211723809639734806e-01
>   -8.992113883794172757e-02
>   1.061556222415527273e-02
>   -2.920395846191836675e-02
>   1.037069716181004964e-03
>   -3.161371576086063895e-02
>   -3.612043404641407385e-02
>   -1.809334659086286878e-02
>   3.662870373600723983e-02
>   1.391056336430290807e-02
>   -1.172024701805174929e-01
>   3.251886867868275521e-02
>   2.396867235334465551e-02
>   3.837332827102124533e-02
>   6.056630689588365923e-02
>   8.321671975043376523e-02
>   1.115621200150082593e-01
>   8.420054612809740879e-02
>   5.823374107493473062e-02
>   7.729794103241893755e-02
>   2.477495629227444152e-02
>   2.972088991663957014e-02
>   3.742060783581174777e-02
>   -1.110223024625156540e-16
>   2.587337514429000063e-02
>   1.527836714091357351e-02
>   1.958896955617406288e-02
>   -1.832210450473931163e-02
>   -1.926657560263266011e-02
>   2.339325805152586701e-02
>   -6.324903516012525539e-02
>   -6.690299051450193657e-02
>   -2.482072685296415893e-02
>   3.064499196744452370e-02
>   3.355998562941886476e-02
>   1.788746275401903452e-02
>   4.613919286422546451e-03
>   -8.927918985562194321e-03
>   1.028462556431128383e-02
>   5.532095657291985491e-02
>   6.604320581321337924e-02
>   3.669973111374175145e-02
>   2.277477855616832914e-02
>   4.808227903197481723e-02
>   4.832747444828244809e-02
>   7.656143177495855490e-03
>   1.245515608493746873e-02
>   2.349500690106676171e-02
>   4.072972204376856808e-03
>   2.516504860752621919e-02
>   2.003738740895273651e-02
>   -2.613223707890222069e-02
>   4.011136596889314232e-03
>   2.548231927644559192e-02
>   1.330938824527588826e-02
>   2.404439993147697296e-02
>   6.907130907663830421e-03
>   6.979484635157226502e-03
>   -3.290848338052448918e-02
>   -1.755191743006401239e-02
>   -3.366674089662069491e-04
>   5.945578987875954624e-05
>   -1.632427050508156174e-02
>   -8.658771138098070308e-02
>   -4.820886804917889901e-02
>   -8.546677486103770871e-03
>   -6.925724668856880761e-03
>   -9.925127350824403116e-04
>   -2.449622387186950467e-02
>   3.123051142945909575e-02
>   5.795788098893345230e-02
>   3.605543122998344785e-02
>   3.302943330800275912e-02
>   7.059531249141720588e-02
>   5.853930993753908574e-02
>   3.905874422983779404e-02
>   4.843263815672965711e-02
>   4.147627035435175191e-02
>   8.400424535113787394e-02
>   9.844201764532001242e-02
>   9.294548499676424935e-02
>   6.497483032833101246e-02
>   1.144645348202695256e-01
>   2.999608390738961461e-02
>   3.085053739416804275e-02
>   2.276726259836320265e-02
>   0.000000000000000000e+00
>   -2.510456168410146738e-02
>   2.116637291906409146e-02
>   -3.321700185738685196e-02
>   3.982853772878908183e-03
>   1.363191485535983349e-02
>   1.564968650026804520e-02
>   1.478997225428510531e-02
>   -3.131685025064945282e-03
>   -3.806954212751323396e-02
>   -8.159214863622976655e-03
>   -7.186257889362090978e-02
>   -9.500427775385178464e-04
>   -3.395150378118699797e-02
>   7.110268582201983989e-03
>   -2.162228010763439512e-02
>   -5.384418762160989025e-02
>   -7.415379224082696563e-03
>   8.122245670091066128e-03
>   -2.878373343427720332e-02
>   -4.544898403509023410e-04
>   2.231065952279343012e-02
>   5.253618584763958266e-02
>   7.567731789121345809e-03
>   1.043630861213364069e-02
>   9.691633727966997292e-03
>   -2.829666135637745605e-03
>   -1.504340107365054191e-03
>   1.140727886561562765e-02
>   1.089115013359434614e-02
>   1.044992233561446715e-02
>   9.693261114407991652e-03
>   -5.238694978638769317e-02
>   -2.457125444725005714e-02
>   1.077886426445628931e-03
>   -4.871118148953068605e-02
>   -6.495809610443054050e-02
>   -3.267035029465242824e-02
>   -2.674999216286094716e-02
>   -3.357327749680671936e-02
>   -8.093857036171048236e-03
>   4.214960036162579415e-02
>   8.643719482737677318e-03
>   -5.065308732882500831e-02
>   -1.275187831141166850e-02
>   4.968104321639105203e-03
>   3.038550497837352871e-02
>   1.292634450475451113e-01
>   9.960248360301909853e-02
>   9.926289065772253561e-02
>   1.218752249462111137e-01
>   6.588591178993197239e-02
>   5.093094629578931443e-02
>   4.116752669646578378e-02
>   4.345115715519703992e-02
>   1.576461619520656832e-02
>   4.396757184635238791e-03
>   -4.521077126215883313e-03
>   1.461648603205449592e-02
>   4.788312032257657780e-02
>   2.755872630307917848e-02
>   6.861615560310868611e-03
>   2.549852881708733476e-02
>   -5.168013319340802880e-03
>   -1.887369212351849845e-02
>   -2.441207169456885429e-02
>   -3.320040226240705827e-02
>   -6.425229768996637558e-02
>   -3.663909065452941594e-02
>   -3.102327088584733161e-02
>   -4.127076305809684875e-02
>   -5.684992379213882341e-03
>   2.906307859990353570e-03
>   -3.900653434877507375e-02
>   1.512074322144520977e-01
>   -2.515933869270309264e-02
>   -6.296389906200300368e-02
>   -9.272701261054544508e-02
>   -4.790753677805792421e-03
>   4.813151476583615862e-02
>   7.650062035746391098e-02
>   3.302890273769037988e-04
>   5.380904266441388639e-03
>   -2.202552482575392823e-03
>   -2.787433399598707173e-04
>   3.384160594702279035e-02
>   1.300796256094960412e-02
>   -1.160214859858521574e-02
>   -6.277244073332632901e-02
>   -1.903552999494984022e-02
>   1.025375794049160350e-02
>   -1.097075016073090215e-03
>   -5.379827426551375691e-02
>   -2.094588005309211409e-02
>   -2.364953944195369306e-02
>   -2.383070948888221796e-02
>   -1.750399960104281893e-02
>   1.497421083089922611e-02
>   2.725070332141532603e-02
>   7.403530041943423567e-02
>   3.001483011466621331e-02
>   4.337594882232209681e-02
>   6.706027060741315271e-02
>   7.233079294473854226e-02
>   1.292045961433705981e-01
>   1.877234340958466863e-02
>   6.212823063689587588e-02
>   8.667098195715983167e-02
>   7.350219246286576746e-02
>   3.159743487146293717e-02
>   5.139887107014962098e-02
>   1.935309979350974263e-02
>   -3.410445703281306251e-04
>   9.794976840847402499e-03
>   -6.959086538445014014e-03
>   1.201927489478310518e-02
>   1.439413096064678932e-02
>   -4.486192051086429489e-02
>   -1.529194554502161241e-02
>   -3.072446651081427171e-02
>   -3.430002826759373513e-02
>   1.718162677056368770e-02
>   3.225957229830100914e-03
>   -1.497698355531706937e-02
>   -1.331288468251978774e-02
>   1.659058944413624448e-02
>   2.663588063070934653e-02
>   -5.922524084111119302e-03
>   5.636060111551793872e-03
>   -2.049342974060008871e-02
>   -3.803998428758581518e-02
>   1.830300118925570763e-03
>   3.424729726582459444e-02
>   -2.895366428311385576e-02
>   -3.386403989355701860e-02
>   -7.079295637878763037e-02
>   -7.093079263306317772e-02
>   3.198451446435424117e-02
>   9.545864656146652028e-02
>   -7.516704766287746198e-02
>   -8.108517870498599400e-02
>   -1.177430403484454047e-01
>   -3.120935658466644780e-02
>   9.223154995107774035e-02
>   -1.941212424528665492e-02
>   3.411902669265831634e-03
>   -2.354139203324806529e-03
>   -3.071645493442498598e-02
>   -4.164925521383888718e-02
>   -3.122691837708191365e-02
>   2.883660684356703641e-02
>   -5.717969520583865428e-02
>   -6.697810496817224735e-03
>   9.441536785215753902e-03
>   4.728317922800373552e-03
>   2.049464471048090264e-03
>   5.739566329777823217e-02
>   7.567444227145320168e-02
>   5.682425425263715191e-02
>   2.127495371418597347e-02
>   5.243610080135335805e-02
>   6.029907063806672074e-02
>   6.969759432272237820e-02
>   5.641399207835956497e-02
>   7.288261681999158581e-02
>   5.756469121404828027e-02
>   7.178193358914231048e-02
>   5.381813355449260872e-02
>   9.644985199153865985e-02
>   6.435194910225061626e-02
>   1.117112490506719791e-01
>   2.439163554038270565e-02
>   2.557084230623229981e-03
>   2.469910898473459682e-02
>   -9.569424158990702534e-03
>   -5.173909847879420987e-02
>   -2.771943460190381958e-02
>   -7.918742305681764071e-03
>   -3.247312870800173057e-02
>   -3.910586948488503634e-03
>   -3.242901716659532529e-02
>   6.020118668182583566e-03
>   1.858335310757686099e-02
>   1.685456044577338108e-02
>   -3.478529517587825026e-02
>   -5.549822951020677575e-02
>   1.016235026400252872e-02
>   2.200445534907724543e-02
>   3.048728364537484081e-02
>   3.272163712735043362e-02
>   2.395435266492118576e-02
>   2.480370438536083633e-02
>   1.056266120762306415e-01
>   -1.082460774310889384e-01
>   -1.347452419485566932e-01
>   -7.714839854654403917e-02
>   -1.900100074423183294e-02
>   -2.368723808155448474e-03
>   0.000000000000000000e+00
>   -2.355757032900079873e-02
>   9.196526397255683216e-03
>   -1.249529199393473178e-03
>   -3.236878688899802459e-02
>   -3.136013706852952554e-02
>   -5.156107379348240372e-04
>   -1.377622880706341757e-01
>   -2.396047220463182192e-02
>   -9.684884856711595269e-02
>   -1.842852002418049473e-02
>   -3.176145780247169315e-02
>   -4.241533961730808988e-02
>   -2.973026167434550393e-02
>   -1.646074567045308079e-02
>   6.668870098842760719e-03
>   5.033457963755305631e-02
>   2.969935511689753005e-02
>   5.231368543525652393e-02
>   5.162632846998616021e-02
>   7.889039094445621236e-02
>   8.296260101450758651e-02
>   9.697524611355656798e-02
>   8.633834112993971077e-02
>   1.005506084517912013e-01
>   1.164298262869764011e-01
>   1.025027965383787376e-01
>   1.135352705294886966e-01
>   1.008843418671770964e-01
>   1.088638311190759378e-01
>   2.884552324651995514e-02
>   3.991830833263365630e-02
>   4.760570909695638342e-02
>   1.693027396115567851e-02
>   3.933182809711910366e-02
>   -6.408816681512249924e-02
>   -5.529609835923893213e-02
>   -2.993717135309542643e-02
>   -8.085331618384095087e-03
>   -6.185204488784304400e-02
>   -1.196921502674397897e-01
>   -4.780768033549070983e-02
>   -1.274389715508722487e-02
>   -1.280925978066266291e-02
>   -4.849996655662441869e-02
>   -3.646866106294993637e-02
>   -2.756873004038262742e-02
>   -5.356826427281805025e-02
>   -6.242776544651362780e-02
>   -6.124211990236372305e-02
>   -5.686055405028850318e-02
>   -2.817431694836830536e-02
>   1.500375567808898136e-02
>   -6.187659459197802914e-02
>   -5.409826477572732273e-02
>   2.261388915804851685e-02
>   6.426257712815597323e-02
>   1.157463639073508244e-02
>   5.004890564395303443e-02
>   -3.950616854542954304e-03
>   -6.239557142348028940e-02
>   -8.200269713949936978e-03
>   -1.251492744667737078e-03
>   -1.265801790937595150e-01
>   -1.768421559080157746e-02
>   2.027397358647520242e-02
>   4.478253635871065619e-03
>   1.878158237154076149e-02
>   6.594154561536602621e-02
>   7.452069498742991405e-02
>   7.496480550402284670e-02
>   9.538428783854202564e-02
>   1.038856363174851527e-01
>   1.424821557236105596e-01
>   1.308412610257474462e-01
>   1.168959152275381719e-01
>   7.850467133577615497e-02
>   7.777115662308897726e-02
>   5.981982514235850701e-02
>   8.319277680590930757e-02
>   5.805864235677821172e-02
>   3.503989261654183451e-02
>   6.941485649918266443e-02
>   3.136830512895127931e-02
>   2.623864649120127845e-02
>   -1.226727174267633336e-02
>   1.110223024625156540e-16
>   -7.376709615168980383e-03
>   -9.038478471914745960e-03
>   6.986774001545778545e-03
>   -3.856365183713572620e-03
>   -8.619184960484249647e-03
>   -3.262580246123072958e-02
>   -4.651261401455147881e-02
>   -3.236697476015598651e-02
>   -1.641180100241046436e-02
>   -6.535594391774748879e-02
>   -1.126080952657532719e-01
>   -1.189511381184812644e-01
>   -5.890481919610351946e-02
>   -5.552142369774434871e-02
>   -6.347500718128468167e-02
>   -7.750984210293726528e-02
>   -4.330385478438258939e-02
>   -7.595236886221326533e-02
>   -1.040841842177327170e-01
>   -7.866565189792984469e-02
>   -9.107533039278314924e-02
>   -9.729503258398433663e-02
>   -5.155961606225628602e-02
>   5.716840813781481900e-02
>   -1.467829770886464047e-02
>   3.556038290053020745e-03
>   2.142707048989228591e-02
>   -3.531625991868403425e-03
>   4.356573820064091329e-02
>   -5.679040673184049259e-02
>   -1.487776052507348845e-02
>   -8.124221123796410149e-02
>   -5.060338391158325511e-03
>   -8.053437474883629044e-03
>   -1.801016783423853296e-02
>   -1.279701804251587305e-02
>   -1.642983927022667601e-02
>   -1.281404297380123181e-02
>   -3.444779062880543030e-03
>   1.814529853593149777e-02
>   3.516420765789823877e-02
>   2.194975082694949897e-02
>   2.529998463330923597e-02
>   4.464264850721472166e-02
>   7.643078317437868030e-02
>   7.041322144265371730e-02
>   8.296155058167570262e-02
>   6.615983653818824362e-02
>   4.794770816378934875e-02
>   8.856734114244479983e-02
>   1.258800873696094280e-01
>   1.389593385184824115e-01
>   1.498281355904477197e-01
>   1.224574555233136630e-01
>   5.483186431966596830e-02
>   5.535402888271356847e-02
>   5.142137446889100127e-02
>   7.029411589955203432e-02
>   5.593633317006369010e-02
>   4.714150671382522084e-02
>   1.297478763856257933e-02
>   4.059793489800239685e-02
>   -3.198355232442939844e-03
>   -1.578471874227083127e-02
>   4.172631884570843219e-04
>   -5.481128123112230521e-03
>   3.958899824310690985e-03
>   4.854634907375310338e-02
>   4.584641828536167862e-02
>   1.283691456912186557e-02
>   2.086772456778712703e-04
>   -3.883286527456911164e-03
>   -6.978568771350529554e-03
>   -8.249607438330544551e-03
>   -1.821024504781104669e-02
>   -6.823049190367941330e-02
>   -2.846369680876015273e-02
>   -4.060232727333634717e-03
>   -9.065014927890668872e-02
>   -8.837841688435754683e-02
>   -1.078654283198097197e-01
>   -3.953937130379669984e-02
>   -2.733287728915720360e-02
>   -8.152640242757383526e-02
>   -1.308357512176841209e-01
>   -8.044444184031515621e-02
>   -6.068031562392728340e-02
>   1.875986720832878429e-02
>   -5.897929249547850805e-02
>   7.073991497246079341e-03
>   -6.090570638678616255e-02
>   -5.462943813919063363e-02
>   -3.270271938640623155e-02
>   -3.791898647128666422e-02
>   1.684196769300894125e-02
>   5.299040124461584789e-02
>   1.727334198115798580e-02
>   -3.262538445267304521e-02
>   -6.460900206302327975e-03
>   -4.187876007718888127e-03
>   2.104051828145839242e-03
>   -6.456440906927712886e-02
>   -8.241220464780019128e-02
>   -1.584243463877277325e-02
>   -4.451124106025378113e-02
>   6.204589027608536922e-02
>   -5.111202513504803369e-02
>   -3.414571659963860917e-02
>   -5.465147093469502337e-02
>   -4.490135130341305070e-02
>   3.297457022298994067e-02
>   1.138019688518973616e-01
>   4.166481086785100985e-02
>   2.925682593430106726e-02
>   8.335791832102096288e-02
>   1.134549440008136845e-01
>   5.318986808574899250e-02
>   6.326665121558505689e-02
>   2.901205218965235977e-02
>   2.709286653167519709e-02
>   6.061274790290466230e-02
>   1.854683369224696676e-02
>   2.902103450321780187e-02
>   -1.466493757378331542e-02
>   -8.450799006366985222e-03
>   3.238752353295620834e-02
>   6.883611128938593726e-03
>   6.304336365859447566e-03
>   2.662321664874278682e-02
>   2.746320655555406498e-02
>   3.603443934644601221e-02
>   2.116640782743439697e-02
>   5.846297720502810491e-03
>   6.489046663897499179e-02
>   -2.212720929445577411e-03
>   -2.189626238306757733e-02
>   1.809448480885464394e-02
>   -4.258279898892736171e-02
>   1.815539971975982381e-02
>   -6.637756744883388516e-02
>   -1.195477794535662885e-01
>   -7.761629593318347675e-02
>   -6.528221527559652237e-02
>   -7.510948509456635835e-02
>   -3.241960469112911691e-02
>   -5.811779465876976136e-02
>   -7.162919591932115360e-02
>   -1.017479140369489388e-01
>   -6.804471305478898557e-02
>   -3.655182112120397564e-02
>   -3.468655899873923643e-02
>   -7.787662238841774887e-02
>   -6.998641259933852110e-02
>   -4.354185850015890313e-02
>   -5.011636796222052048e-02
>   -3.801528925170127859e-02
>   1.260090902987887063e-02
>   4.423447876462893724e-02
>   1.283787124659774292e-02
>   4.949812209368315008e-02
>   -7.727269529949953863e-03
>   9.282469058985345911e-03
>   -1.151166856591892551e-02
>   -5.171058003512418733e-03
>   -1.198847871951366773e-02
>   -1.294468509956125946e-03
>   2.798713296447363774e-02
>   3.586060178983307978e-02
>   -7.076132206619289988e-04
>   -9.774184452153625302e-02
>   -1.060006385825577602e-01
>   -6.756566877045661057e-02
>   -1.298748714533518867e-01
>   -1.005912904186360146e-01
>   -9.437547579407315479e-02
>   -5.801209316061123333e-02
>   -4.550554546462615146e-02
>   -2.970686610155373608e-02
>   2.036190620496108883e-02
>   -6.334074918455723235e-03
>   1.300144335549104913e-01
>   8.996752652747164181e-02
>   -3.443754124748399370e-03
>   2.744909628221592346e-02
>   8.856880872205730171e-02
>   3.401716662605136499e-02
>   9.291635086396965448e-03
>   2.668220571054702450e-02
>   3.144660703649948541e-02
>   4.554336909825346114e-02
>   7.471406035640879018e-03
>   4.177724765576401600e-03
>   2.949815659979121429e-03
>   7.726256994904215358e-03
>   -1.183780950302602830e-02
>   -8.331527641184180433e-03
>   -6.449427336969112967e-03
>   -2.357439184548476563e-03
>   1.572601140811527576e-02
>   5.618800754135233610e-03
>   -4.734364951055336501e-03
>   -4.310085917632522357e-02
>   -1.000801848423465978e-02
>   -7.031537055423214833e-02
>   -9.082154353565163873e-02
>   -7.165060423128888356e-02
>   -4.435286882606784276e-02
>   -5.449526586614975021e-02
>   -5.823660056605653446e-02
>   -1.177647112629865989e-01
>   -1.460010232247108408e-01
>   -9.955322836098917660e-02
>   -1.104748314340267545e-01
>   -7.259346385162268600e-02
>   -1.106944801930266620e-02
>   -3.681924821616411325e-02
>   -9.659448510554280443e-03
>   -1.843394276381193908e-02
>   3.517119076792252219e-03
>   3.530318740158017166e-02
>   -2.448237276752554537e-02
>   -8.324086961505566817e-02
>   -5.846226565018575183e-02
>   -4.413306998637939182e-02
>   -3.028123726983295017e-02
>   -1.749517293355967729e-02
>   -4.239388057717285996e-02
>   -7.463936401822154898e-02
>   -7.610312681716457917e-02
>   -3.400887292327570144e-02
>   1.279300671485920637e-01
>   -8.000494443979655479e-03
>   6.057720685599143895e-02
>   2.338262587606632081e-02
>   3.357008922451221178e-02
>   4.446097061532966466e-02
>   4.985567466467188957e-02
>   -3.729651991065656425e-02
>   -1.123452980897715614e-02
>   -1.290967152574694354e-02
>   -1.169785420119778818e-03
>   4.339304671458821261e-03
>   7.960208457236550572e-03
>   1.612425145210272248e-02
>   -1.357566069003079967e-02
>   -1.897636113688777604e-02
>   -2.127467682317307762e-02
>   5.688677706903066955e-02
>   1.167397147122162249e-03
>   -5.238090444095563902e-02
>   -8.033229756483753481e-02
>   -5.638668031346266707e-02
>   -8.770126909852105079e-02
>   -1.139703122313763251e-01
>   -1.091441073080444135e-01
>   -9.308666913218882621e-02
>   -1.318168247245212754e-01
>   2.785215405331337157e-02
>   -1.706111939405730027e-03
>   -1.044319809233721918e-01
>   -1.517829994094719304e-01
>   -1.054769050331120228e-01
>   1.423877469064789847e-01
>   1.153685494681763735e-02
>   -8.706359502361496472e-03
>   1.135425261481345927e-03
>   1.441192789427614418e-03
>   -1.482166852378000166e-02
>   -2.741693694998395547e-02
>   3.842834910067111087e-02
>   -3.016686231083920422e-03
>   -6.272337600095162502e-02
>   -2.945125575841017751e-02
>   -8.265012146342437527e-02
>   -6.854100855556741201e-02
>   -5.195084362038110415e-02
>   -7.411749468435571697e-02
>   -2.486286453376224115e-02
>   -6.187847656496281434e-02
>   -2.968894745884106956e-02
>   1.762643206525443818e-02
>   1.294560182734616482e-02
>   4.221917108300238253e-02
>   9.920310650409752684e-02
>   8.521827899351425151e-02
>   9.774522370312288544e-03
>   7.499195679634462763e-02
>   2.732722326513375988e-02
>   6.350451310634608326e-02
>   6.490460864797181761e-02
>   5.707981988600985268e-02
>   1.844500040724739165e-02
>   1.417147248904337964e-02
>   7.990194193126673450e-03
>   1.009520255724344340e-02
>   3.898843403253271500e-02
>   -1.155609759566522676e-02
>   -2.519440484900131727e-03
>   2.253313653278327111e-03
>   5.827885242445790537e-03
>   9.190962784846823386e-03
>   1.160732911085857189e-03
>   -5.275909555766289394e-03
>   3.381787516318887632e-02
>   -2.721033970278663450e-02
>   -5.244285970630779836e-02
>   4.875759422490227868e-02
>   4.600835429833582957e-03
>   -3.087228383610574056e-02
>   8.917388299658379758e-03
>   -3.113625653331408838e-02
>   -1.478572370454844798e-02
>   4.940881828154741751e-02
>   -2.336867791265717642e-02
>   -5.379793719052139434e-02
>   -4.291909741123584032e-02
>   -7.477199403031892233e-02
>   -7.442517841205104068e-02
>   -1.248234745779867039e-01
>   -1.379519428221240851e-01
>   -1.371746383883072351e-01
>   -1.410640080491438464e-01
>   -7.153402382767853895e-02
>   -7.951004471596795353e-02
>   -1.459334568545657129e-01
>   -6.895284700299986191e-03
>   2.746149785201490445e-03
>   2.308385727351258687e-03
>   -7.994019877111374628e-02
>   -5.890325063153001306e-02
>   -8.784983164698587088e-02
>   -6.129444879220657949e-02
>   -6.467969716770757826e-02
>   -5.258220008153868807e-02
>   -3.986417666108588165e-02
>   -6.480401394489507250e-02
>   -7.151191855893396232e-02
>   1.055472282177393750e-01
>   5.440200566045894082e-02
>   3.656338981196360916e-02
>   6.555135724368527095e-02
>   8.778637220420631992e-02
>   7.209217548046492618e-02
>   4.669587885186798903e-02
>   5.361773176019690723e-02
>   2.100601311910893498e-02
>   6.322721469066044930e-02
>   6.324133263799930349e-02
>   2.644507624189262884e-02
>   6.493048045675509083e-02
>   4.137328830399938928e-02
>   -1.590679399124483862e-02
>   1.906620985511198185e-03
>   1.176733236402961735e-02
>   -2.724327187162875474e-02
>   -1.694316454009803241e-03
>   7.151084022793061101e-03
>   -2.518011196291669584e-02
>   -6.830186397384752084e-03
>   3.839225472878626810e-04
>   -6.383522099629515556e-03
>   3.213803800869874383e-02
>   6.646280411769012186e-03
>   3.469305590503041214e-03
>   3.161514171528406747e-03
>   3.286238069597990918e-03
>   1.312624149812902097e-02
>   1.332620754499003191e-02
>   2.640736755382855350e-02
>   3.996890614732073743e-02
>   -2.128863487235810315e-02
>   -7.933393845336322858e-02
>   -3.302483636109176945e-02
>   -1.015654416187094511e-01
>   -1.325651062865587093e-01
>   -1.160991618245051926e-01
>   -1.064432056694104567e-01
>   -1.184449020589762869e-01
>   -6.400724828316428638e-02
>   -1.016812531739407222e-01
>   -7.798906219928736228e-02
>   -8.767094074204545562e-02
>   -8.131929970818713160e-03
>   -4.266889541076873682e-03
>   -8.051025079016255193e-02
>   -8.142489159399107779e-02
>   -6.463343952452976771e-02
>   -3.477208304841689079e-02
>   -6.169485922106210385e-02
>   -7.794801571513843008e-02
>   -5.875547413448400924e-02
>   -2.948747628264225540e-02
>   -2.468786350077079028e-02
>   6.316931852297980043e-03
>   1.675770593459768865e-02
>   8.440158329731495268e-03
>   3.407307521354102642e-02
>   4.046558954161111332e-02
>   5.333240427857222077e-02
>   9.984317230508371610e-02
>   6.380628672903065901e-02
>   6.821895425172957994e-02
>   7.726852029029263047e-02
>   1.099879223841040976e-01
>   1.154725109215001821e-01
>   1.289915848947860155e-01
>   1.168403187068005611e-01
>   7.601204755920465406e-02
>   5.760226131262197180e-02
>   6.111537335727673659e-02
>   4.615846941988716035e-02
>   5.338692740816225468e-02
>   5.555730080338849852e-02
>   9.043577779408418227e-02
>   7.540903584304714524e-02
>   7.434934358590894465e-02
>   -4.715512399759397288e-02
>   7.006223732701544193e-03
>   3.364841554370112675e-03
>   1.690409671780922218e-02
>   1.103833164924136745e-02
>   1.126494343287030159e-02
>   4.057932819030787841e-03
>   1.368619273598631336e-03
>   4.626015404370703576e-02
>   2.132559203921788327e-03
>   -1.265471233206300061e-02
>   -4.516990638789936119e-03
>   -7.155526544551302215e-03
>   -1.352277613288392633e-02
>   2.621463144352664809e-02
>   1.939461416689092221e-02
>   6.185211299288173592e-03
>   8.045623312930225146e-03
>   4.407589536537970254e-03
>   1.191666034032462518e-02
>   6.547637500250988452e-03
>   6.270007122786691589e-03
>   2.630044414796584018e-03
>   5.806308029044277008e-03
>   8.511179399315754734e-04
>   -2.362464244201878394e-02
>   -3.380972184650721246e-03
>   6.357541814028117022e-03
>   1.537197145284752153e-02
>   6.342725900758727775e-02
>   7.259079807480606217e-02
>   1.157786344750846297e-01
>   7.184128864328309660e-02
>   -1.035335901320000307e-02
>   4.168878403254561160e-02
>   6.321671510862214571e-02
>   6.721673864842980795e-02
>   -8.634059593854637171e-02
>   -6.710734873617735241e-02
>   -5.401885723027677333e-02
>   -9.033267165973468682e-02
>   6.077874509055947172e-03
>   -3.288646725657162762e-02
>   -6.980608224949735874e-02
>   -9.304199209365759948e-02
>   4.102947654724820037e-02
>   1.304906824207752170e-02
>   3.284161330384344213e-02
>   -1.083123574638507891e-01
>   -3.474140936233205412e-02
>   -3.115680830226313924e-02
>   -8.954540738243413345e-02
>   -4.195714073667794475e-02
>   -8.509552666629494055e-02
>   -9.544602778678318300e-02
>   -7.612007930937042532e-02
>   -5.777839588658773007e-02
>   -5.979117785777282590e-02
>   -9.303876566862379072e-04
>   -1.835442822550326092e-03
>   5.093692506767105721e-02
>   7.321897028698953758e-03
>   2.843994192835286317e-02
>   3.652328472779242663e-02
>   5.976919248128853557e-02
>   5.578086382840818924e-02
>   -4.312149138461496278e-02
>   7.607358466719998935e-02
>   5.186506528253109760e-02
>   1.066872150488835103e-01
>   2.317293301517714399e-02
>   8.358124769813657373e-02
>   1.212137536909758118e-01
>   1.088231327200454568e-01
>   2.702684551830986104e-02
>   2.980740712067009301e-02
>   7.117852449560413408e-02
>   5.029681501193783433e-02
>   6.926432731488418870e-02
>   3.138751560408248320e-02
>   5.240655701285723556e-02
>   5.934528699975138988e-02
>   7.562571076104612766e-02
>   5.959577823875922276e-02
>   4.831664684117192854e-03
>   1.507431192400966735e-02
>   1.757792668096593014e-03
>   -5.219913345067189736e-03
>   -7.026869437085692116e-03
>   -4.846569770470751659e-03
>   -5.317193298629660503e-03
>   -6.900490373682011125e-03
>   -4.672818975354944837e-03
>   -5.622143765235121382e-04
>   1.316040200243101532e-02
>   -4.197649878046133542e-03
>   2.545967639584312270e-03
>   3.191690482571410414e-03
>   1.116690262505298792e-03
>   7.411148270822009998e-03
>   9.477059769268714184e-03
>   7.852044959877985120e-03
>   -1.756565812885621525e-03
>   -4.869098454477943649e-03
>   -2.685139186935664446e-03
>   -1.085590845068482024e-02
>   1.059285359914305391e-02
>   1.849516730946226817e-02
>   4.222865377134421561e-02
>   -8.785324111355796717e-03
>   1.874835920114170662e-03
>   9.396433027552286710e-02
>   5.248701611436867864e-02
>   6.487698256645951789e-02
>   9.643773387012782861e-02
>   7.471527239577763213e-02
>   9.961300302901632264e-02
>   8.589476044726551685e-02
>   3.321503310077345006e-02
>   -1.211545818919109729e-01
>   5.532271038215685888e-02
>   -1.409394383388486438e-01
>   -8.514245610785636798e-02
>   -4.886889620580692206e-02
>   -4.712974967948441174e-02
>   -2.021370739854932985e-02
>   -2.971153093296480252e-02
>   -1.479922118615240034e-02
>   -1.271505988488993433e-01
>   1.317582259028932667e-01
>   4.529932159377814127e-02
>   1.231348201919263419e-02
>   -9.872668484965235747e-03
>   -7.924516778866730338e-02
>   -5.253905352146087671e-02
>   -4.088819168557034089e-02
>   -7.392603214977239157e-02
>   1.711047770440399240e-03
>   -3.491752950501547659e-02
>   -1.346242779247391885e-02
>   -2.440079125723870757e-02
>   -1.020757962795454388e-02
>   3.651582367707101318e-02
>   5.252042094050879406e-02
>   4.758564985168128869e-02
>   2.220446049250313081e-16
>   8.860686880938839494e-02
>   8.850994833649650229e-02
>   6.930848923131482930e-02
>   1.034439095036600031e-01
>   7.877308384639736261e-02
>   1.313369785954572877e-01
>   1.271483104168850686e-01
>   6.367449317819257049e-02
>   3.854436006555339578e-02
>   4.785932231168799067e-02
>   6.582239699615949347e-02
>   -2.446832169975494964e-03
>   1.222332317369036192e-02
>   1.034711285034142780e-02
>   -2.295209704164843934e-03
>   -1.353755519017434128e-02
>   -1.346053714582767791e-03
>   4.093075312305502478e-03
>   1.933078846524105554e-04
>   -1.002784315773430635e-02
>   -1.087087238633070718e-02
>   -1.189732614960203883e-02
>   -8.124852809278201859e-03
>   -4.803677212548401743e-03
>   -7.919173430258996671e-03
>   -5.867875309395961803e-03
>   -9.175338677694863665e-03
>   9.765872837728312161e-03
>   1.361864184454894544e-02
>   9.301200706621270964e-03
>   -2.026660805014443567e-03
>   5.906830317137512498e-04
>   7.382336514353160517e-03
>   8.410538789687949102e-03
>   1.535361143379543325e-02
>   9.231776277094427829e-03
>   3.122655500871762690e-03
>   -3.942937463410095544e-03
>   7.929557208005727498e-03
>   3.413561032196532619e-03

## [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyK01.png)just got wrong figure[enter image

## description here][2], using python 3.7.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=-1)
data.columns =['A']
data.hist('A', bins=20, density=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain what output you expect to see?

Comment: normal probability density figure, the range of y axis between 0.0 to1.0, I got my figure result, the value of y over 17, I am a little confused.